# Creating own library based on a source library in Visual Studio c#

Tags: c#, oop, adapter, facade

I realize that there are some methods that the existing library i.e. System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting don't support.
For example, 
If I want the Series to plot x , y values including parameters like increments in x .

How could I add another overloading method to the existing System library, My supervisor mentioned a common technique called Facade pattern and also Adapter pattern, but I really have no clue of how to deal with these things.

Thanks

My way to handle this problem is to create my own class, to inherit these library... but then I realise the work is too heavy, because all the codes created by Windows Forms use the library from System, not my library... 
e.g. this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
 they are using Charting.Chart, If i create my own chart class called Mychart i would have to replace every chart by mychart ..... How can I avoid this?

Is that anyway to append some new overload methods into Microsoft library without doing too much work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you consider using [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb383977.aspx)?

Extension methods provide you a way to add functionality to an existing assembly without changing that assembly.  You could add an overloaded method without having to change the original assembly and without needing to change the currently existing code that uses that assembly.

Note there are limitations to extension methods.

If you want to add a new overloaded extension method to the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` class then you could try something like this:

Add a static class to your project that will contain the extension methods:

```
public static class ChartExtensions
{
    public static void Show(this Chart chart, bool includeIncrements)
    {
        // Do your modifications to the chart here ...
        chart.Show();
    }

}
```

Now you can use the new method with normal chart objects:

```
Chart chart1 = new Chart();  // <-- Normal chart object
//chart1.Show();             // <-- standard chart method
chart1.Show(true);           // <-- your new overloaded method
```

**EDIT:** Not sure exactly what you want.  Something like this perhaps?

```
public static class DataPointCollectionExtension
{
    // Adds a new point to the end of the collection, with a spedified y and
    // a value of x that is dx larger than the last value.
    public static void AddDXY(this DataPointCollection points, double dx, double y)
    {
        double x = 0.0; // Default starting x if there are no points in the collection.
        if (points.Count() > 0) { x = points.Last().XValue + dx; }

        points.Add(new DataPoint(x, y));
    }
}
```

Then use like this:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddDXY(0.5, 5.2);
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddDXY(0.5, 4.2);
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddDXY(1.0, 6.2);
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddDXY(0.7, 4.8);
```

Comment: Cheers, I think this is kind of the thing I want, but I'm not sure yet if this is the ultimate solution to my problem or whether there is better method to deal with this.

I will try it first and get back to you shortly!

Comment: In fact, I want to overload the method called AddY :[link](http:// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) _AddY_ But I'm not sure how you do it... I just tried but i couldn't get the AddY green light up like yours.

Comment: @elpsyCongroo still not quite sure what you want but I made an edit to this post.

Comment: I got argument out of range unhandled... is it because x does not have an initial value to start with?

Comment: thanks for helping me. I just removed the 0.5 increment, and it turns out to plot Y = 5, with x incrementing 1 each time .... Let me try to pass in a list of Y

Comment: I mean the overloaded version appear in the documentation but it seems that they didnt work

Comment: @elpsyCongroo Unfortunately the example I gave you was not a good one.  I did check that it compiled but I did not try it - sorry.  It turns out that AddY already has a class overload `AddY(params object[] yValue)`.  Class methods always take precedence over extension methods.  You will have to make sure your extension method has a unique Method Signature so that it does not conflict.  If you still need help to debug then I recommend posting a new question with your code so far and the exception method. Good Luck!

Comment: lol I see, you should have told me earlier, it wasted me whole day sitting there and getting frustrated..... anyway thanks for all your hard work

Comment: @elpsyCongroo I am really sorry.  I should be more careful with my examples.

Comment: I just realised your code works if you replace AddY by AddY1 , it seems that you can't have the same name, as it always priotises the default methods, but then there is another error lol

Comment: @elpsyCongroo Updated again.  Based on your comment, I renamed the extension method as AddDXY (Add delta x and y).  I tested it and it does seem to work.  Let me know if you have any issues with it.

Comment: it works. I modified the function a bit.

            public static void AddY1(this DataPointCollection points, double start, double [] y, double increment)
        {
                double[] Y = y;
                for (int i = 0; i < Y.Length; i++)
                {
                double x = start + i*increment;
                DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(x, Y[i]);
                points.Add(dp);
                }

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use inheritance in this specific case you would create a class that extends `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` like this.

```
public class MyCharting : System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting 
{

}
```

Then you would take parts of `Charting` that you want to dehave differently and `override` the methods that you want to change their original behaviour. You will not gonna be able to do that to any method only to `virtual` ones.

Regarding additional functionality like adding additional properties and fields you should be able to do that no problem as long as `base` class does not already have fields with same names. [More on inheritance.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_inheritance.htm)

Comment: HI , I 'm very happy that you tried to help me out. 
Let me explain my problems better, I tried your method before, but then I realised
    this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
    this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
As you can see the winform designer i.e. Machine generated code is using the original Class called charting.Chart.... SO if I go onto developing a new class called Mycharting , I would have to replace every Chart by Mycharting which is so much work to do.

Comment: If you want to use that extra functionality then unforutnatelly yes. You could use dependency injection frameworks to replace `Charting` instance with `MyCharting` but it highly depends on the way your program is written, talk to the manager ask if there's a way to inject charting.

Comment: RE:LIUFA , I'm now watching a youtube video about Decorator Pattern, don't know if this is the key to the problem? I.e instead of creating my own class object, I appened toppings" functionalities on the existing class object such as Chart, and Series classes.